# how to know if user clicked spinner android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have implemented multiple(seven) spinners and populated them with three options: Yes, No, and Unknown. And "Unknown" is the default option. Now I want to know whether user clicked spinner or not. Since the default option can also be a valid answer, I could not work with getSelectedItemPosition() in Spinner class.

All I want to know is whether user clicked that particular spinner or not, so that I can generate alert message depending on this Info.

Comment: what is wrong with getSelectedItemPosition() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is read the [Spinners guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) on the Android developer site. Having done that, you'll find this handy example:

```
public class MySpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpy,
First Set OnItemSelectedListener to each Spinner and then check in method,

if you have more spinner then getSelectedItem() using below code inside onItemSeleted Method,

```
String str1= (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String str2= (String) spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
```